# how do I merge these arrays?

Tags: php

I have this array structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [timestamp] => 1310394569
                    [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [0] => A static tweet here from the static xml
                        ) 

                       [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                       (
                            [0] => http://www.google.com
                        )

                    [type] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [0] => static
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
               (
                    [timestamp] => 1310117641
                    [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [0] => http://www.facebook.com/
                    )

                [type] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [0] => facebook
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [timestamp] => 1309856547
                [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [0] => http://www.facebook.com/
                    )

                [type] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [0] => facebook
                    )

            )
```

But I want to get rid of the outer containing array...so I'm left with this:

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
            (
                [timestamp] => 1310394569
                [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [0] => A static tweet here from the static xml
                    ) 

                   [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                   (
                        [0] => http://www.google.com
                    )

                [type] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [0] => static
                    )

            )

       [1] => Array
            (
                [timestamp] => 1310394569
                [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [0] => A static tweet here from the static xml
                    ) 

                   [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                   (
                        [0] => http://www.google.com
                    )

                [type] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [0] => static
                    )

            )
```

array merge isn't doing anything at all....is there any way to do this?

Comment: Where is `$array[1][1]` supposed to end up?

Comment: $a=$arr1+$arr2 this will merge two arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a bit unclear, but assuming you want to turn this

```
array(
    array(
         array(…)
    )
    array(
         array(…)
    )
)
```

into

```
array(
     array(…)
     array(…)
)
```

this'll do:

```
$array = array_map('current', $array);
```

---

If you want to turn this

```
array(
    array(
        array(…)
    )
    array(
        array(…)
        array(…)
    )
)
```

into

```
array(
    array(…)
    array(…)
    array(…)
)
```

this should do:

```
$array = array_reduce($array, function ($result, $array) {
             return array_merge($result, $array);
         }, array());
```

Comment: apologies I can see how the question might have been unclear after re-reading it. That almost works but in my first post in the first block of code I posted you can see that in array [1] there are two nested arrays....but using the array_map function only returns the first array...I'm only getting the first nested array returned from each of the first level arrays

Comment: And that's why I asked what should happen to `$array[1][1]`… Maybe you could make your question easier to understand, format the array better, use shorter examples?

Comment: Yes. That's it. I'm going to format the question now. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For multidimensional arrays you have to use [array_merge_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).